# how can i load my js function from js file on my nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a small website, I'm a beginner in javascript and nodejs, I create a small server with nodejs but I do not know how to load my file.js in the server  help please.
this is my server :

```
enter code here

let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(req, res)
{ 

    if(req.url === "/")
    {
        fs.readFile("index.html", "UTF-8", function(err, html)
        {
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            res.end(html);
        });
    }else if(req.url.match("\.css$"))
    {
        var cssPath = path.join(__dirname, '', req.url);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(cssPath, "UTF-8");
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
        fileStream.pipe(res);

    }else if(req.url.match("\.png$")){
        var imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '', req.url);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(imagePath);
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "images/png"});
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }else if (req.url.match("\.jpg$")) {
         var imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '', req.url);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(imagePath);
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "images/jpg"});
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }
    else
    {
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end("No Page Found");
    }
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

and this is a part from my javascript file

```
$(function(){
    let navMain=document.querySelector('nav');
    let ul=document.getElementById('mainUl');
    let li=document.createElement('li');
    let a=document.createElement('a');
    let login=document.createTextNode('Login');

        $(window).on('scroll',function(){
            const navMainTopMesure=navMain.offsetTop;
            if($(window).scrollTop() && window.scrollY>=navMainTopMesure){
                $('nav').addClass('fixed');
                a.appendChild(login);
                li.appendChild(a);
                ul.appendChild(li);
                a.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    document.querySelector('.login').style.display='flex';
                });
                return 0;

            }else{
                $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
                ul.removeChild(li);
            }
        })
  });

  $(function(){


    window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        if(e.target == document.querySelector('.register')){
            document.querySelector('.register').style.display='none';
        }

    })

    window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        if(e.target == document.querySelector('.login') ){
             document.querySelector('.login').style.display='none';
        }
    })

  let date =new Date();
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML=date.toDateString();
  document.querySelector('.sign-up').addEventListener('click',function(){
      document.querySelector('.register').style.display='flex';

  })

  document.querySelector('.closeRegister').addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.querySelector('.register').style.display='none';
  })

  document.querySelector('.sign-in').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.querySelector('.login').style.display='flex';
})

document.querySelector('.closeLogin').addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.querySelector('.login').style.display='none';
})

$('.mobile-nav').on('click',function(){
    $('.nav-main ul').toggleClass('drop');
   $('.mobile-nav i').toggleClass('fa-times');
})  
    });



function smoothScroll(target,duration)
{
    var target = document.querySelector(target);
    var targetposition = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var startposition = window.pageYOffset;
    var distance = targetposition-startposition;
    var starttime = null;
```

i just want to execute my function in javascripte file in my server.
my probleme when i execute the html file on the localhost in the browser evry think is okey but any javascript event happend

Comment: Please copy your code in your question instead of linking images

Comment: Hey, your images don't show a file.js.

Comment: i add my server code

Comment: frankly speaking, what you are doing in Node doesn't make sense. 
Where is your file.js? and where is it being used? Like if it is being used in nodeJs and since you are using ES5 Statements, then you would need to `require` it in node. if you are using it in frontend, then you would need to add a script tag with `src` to reference. if you need to have frontend which interacts with backend, then you should google search for `full Stack app` or `ejs` for beginning and if you want it to run when user have a reached particular route, then call it inside that route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create a folder in your main app directory, called 'frontend' or 'src' or 'public' and in that folder create the directory that will be used by your index.html file. Throw your JS file in there wherever you want it.

In your main server or app.js file for node, do app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'whatevernameyouchoseforyourfrontendfiles')));

And after you serve the initial HTML files every time your server gets a request for a file it will know where to look.

Comment: hey, thank you for answering me, but what is the type of app? what kind of variable it is.

Comment: Oh no, my mistake. You're using Express. I would suggest using Express.js, not barebones Node, unless you're trying to test yourself of show that you can. Express is an app framework for node, kind of like how React is a webpage framework for javascript.

Comment: If you want to continue down the path of using pure node, google 'static files without express.' If you want to start using Express, google 'basic express app,' then after that, google 'serve static files with express', to figure out how to send the initial index.html file, and set a folder structure, which is what I showed in my initial answer.